# How to get Windows 10 to recognize my MicroSD card?

Tags: windows-10, disk-management, micro-sd-card

My Surface Pro 4 won't recognize a 32gb MicroSD card after I screwed up trying to load-then-delete RetroPie.  Today I tried loading RetroPie images onto a 32gb MicroSD card, but I didn't seem to do so properly, so I decided I would try to clear anything I loaded onto the SD card, and start from scratch.

Following the instructions on the bottom of [this LifeHacker post](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-super-easy-r-1261113524), I tried to delete partitions on the SD card.  I think I did something wrong, and I don't know how to get my SD card back to normal.

First, Windows does show there is a USB Drive (D:) in my File Explorer, but when I click on it, it shows "Please insert a disk into USB Drive (D:), as shown below.

[image: Insert a Disk Screenshot]

When I go to Disk Management I only see two partitions for the drive, and when I right-click either, all options other than *Help* are greyed out.

[image: Disk Management]

I'm not very good with this type of work, and I don't know how I might have ruined the SD card or what needs done to bring it back to a "normal" usable state.  Please advise what I need to do to make this SD card usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Disk Management right click in the unallocated space for D: then select "create partition" in the wizard that appears you want to create a primary partition.

Click through that wizard and it should set up the drive for you.

Comment: Worked perfect, though FYI on my Windows 10 machine it is the "New Simple Volume Wizard"